# custom calendar using javascript

Tags: javascript, calendar

I want to create a calendar with date picker using java script of my own design without using any j-query library. I found one code and i created calendar with that but i am not to find how to five next and previous month button in calendar and i want to highlight the current date. I also need to click on date to perform certain operations. How do it do it?? Please help me.

This is my code

```
// these are labels for the days of the week
cal_days_labels = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
// these are human-readable month name labels, in order

cal_months_labels = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April',
                 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September',
                 'October', 'November', 'December'];
// these are the days of the week for each month, in order
cal_days_in_month = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];

// this is the current date
cal_current_date = new Date();

function Calendar(month, year) {
this.month = (isNaN(month) || month == null) ? cal_current_date.getMonth() : month;
this.year = (isNaN(year) || year == null) ? cal_current_date.getFullYear() : year;
this.html = '';
}


Calendar.prototype.generateHTML = function () {

// get first day of month
var firstDay = new Date(this.year, this.month, 1);
var startingDay = firstDay.getDay();

// find number of days in month
var monthLength = cal_days_in_month[this.month];

// compensate for leap year
if (this.month == 1) { // February only!
    if ((this.year % 4 == 0 && this.year % 100 != 0) || this.year % 400 == 0) {
        monthLength = 29;
    }
}

// do the header
var monthName = cal_months_labels[this.month]
var html = '<table class="calendar-table">';
html += '<tr><th colspan="7">';
html += monthName + "&nbsp;" + this.year;
html += '</th></tr>';
html += '<tr class="calendar-header">';
for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    html += '<td class="calendar-header-day">';
    html += cal_days_labels[i];
    html += '</td>';
}
html += '</tr><tr>';

// fill in the days
var day = 1;
// this loop is for is weeks (rows)
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    // this loop is for weekdays (cells)
    for (var j = 0; j <= 6; j++) {
        html += '<td class="calendar-day">';
        if (day <= monthLength && (i > 0 || j >= startingDay)) {
            html += day;
            day++;
        }
        html += '</td>';
    }
    // stop making rows if we've run out of days
    if (day > monthLength) {
        break;
    } else {
        html += '</tr><tr>';
    }
}
html += '</tr></table>';

this.html = html;
}

Calendar.prototype.getHTML = function () {
return this.html;
}
```

this is my script to get calendar:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var cal = new Calendar();
    cal.generateHTML();
    document.write(cal.getHTML());
</script>
```

Comment: Turns out, working with times, dates, timezones, UTC offsets is a lot more complex than you would think at first glance. Specially if you start to include the really odd stuff in history where days where added/removed from calander years by rulers. For educational purposes very good, but if you want to create a product i would suggest not reinventing the wheel and selecting a library (like momentjs for instance; http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var curMonth = parseInt(document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMonth").innerText);
document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMonthDDD").innerText = convertMonth_ddToDDD(curMonth);
previous();

function previous() {
  var curMonth = parseInt(document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMonth").innerText);
  var curYear = parseInt(document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_lblYear").innerText)

  var prevMonth = getPreviousMonth(curMonth, curYear);
  var prevYear = getPreviousYear(curMonth, curYear);

  document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMonth").innerText = prevMonth;
  document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMonthDDD").innerText = convertMonth_ddToDDD(prevMonth);
  document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_lblYear").innerText = prevYear;

  createCalenderTable(prevMonth, prevYear);

  return false;
}

function next() {

  var curMonth = parseInt(document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMonth").innerText);
  var curYear = parseInt(document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_lblYear").innerText)

  var nextMonth = getNextMonth(curMonth, curYear);
  var nextYear = getNextYear(curMonth, curYear);

  document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMonth").innerText = nextMonth;
  document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMonthDDD").innerText = convertMonth_ddToDDD(nextMonth);
  document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_lblYear").innerText = nextYear;

  createCalenderTable(nextMonth, nextYear);
  return false;
}

function getPreviousMonth(curMonth, curYear) {
  //alert("current: "+ curMonth +" "+curYear);
  var prevMonth;
  //for month: ...3, 2, 1, 12, 11, 10...
  if (curMonth == 1) {
    prevMonth = 12;
  } else {
    prevMonth = curMonth - 1;
  }

  //alert(prevMonth + " " + prevYear);

  return prevMonth;
}

function getNextMonth(curMonth, curYear) {
  //alert("current: "+ curMonth +" "+curYear);
  var nextMonth;
  //for month: ...3, 2, 1, 12, 11, 10...
  if (curMonth == 12) {
    nextMonth = 1;
  } else {
    nextMonth = curMonth + 1;
  }

  //alert(prevMonth + " " + prevYear);

  return nextMonth;
}

function getPreviousYear(curMonth, curYear) {
  //alert("current: " + curMonth + " " + curYear);
  //var prevMonth;
  var prevYear;

  //for prev year if month==12 the decrement
  if (curMonth == 1) {
    prevYear = curYear - 1;
  } else {
    prevYear = curYear;
  }

  return prevYear;
}

function getNextYear(curMonth, curYear) {
  //alert("current: " + curMonth + " " + curYear);
  //var prevMonth;
  var nextYear;

  //for prev year if month==12 the decrement
  if (curMonth == 12) {
    nextYear = curYear + 1;
  } else {
    nextYear = curYear;
  }

  return nextYear;
}

function isThisLeapYear(year) {

  //temporary taken static
  if (year % 4 == 0 || year % 100 == 100) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function createCalenderTable(monthNo, year) {

  var totalDays = getTotalDaysForThisMonth(monthNo, year);
  var firstDateDayNo = getMonthFirstDate_DayNo(monthNo, year);

  var tableHeader = "<table  style='box-shadow:3px 3px 24px 1px gray' cellPadding='10' border='1px solid black'>";
  tableHeader += "<tr style='background-color:lightgray;'><th>Sun</th><th>Mon</th><th>Tue</th><th>Wed</th><th>Thu</th><th>Fri</th><th>Sat</th>" + trEnd;
  var trStart = "<tr>";
  var trEnd = "</tr>";
  var tableEnd = "</table>";
  var datesInRow = "";
  var rowContent = "";

  var i = 1;
  //alert(totalDays);
  while (i <= totalDays) {

    //week
    rowContent += trStart;
    for (var j = 0; j <= 6 && i <= totalDays; j++, i++) {

      while (firstDateDayNo > 0) {
        rowContent += "<td id='0'></td>";
        firstDateDayNo--;
        j++;
      }
      rowContent += "<td id='" + i + "' onclick='return setThisSelectedDateToTextBox(" + i + ");'>" + i + "</td>";
    }
    rowContent += trEnd;
    //i+=7;
  }

  //var tableOuter = "<table><tr><td>"+"</td></tr></table>";
  document.getElementById("divCal").innerHTML = tableHeader + rowContent + tableEnd;
}

function getMonthFirstDate_DayNo(monthNo, year) {

  var dt = new Date(year, monthNo - 1, 1);
  // alert(dt+"----"+dt.getDay());
  return dt.getDay();
}

function getTotalDaysForThisMonth(monthNo, year) {

  switch (monthNo) {
    case 1:
    case 3:
    case 5:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 10:
    case 12:
      return 31;
      break;

    case 4:
    case 6:
    case 9:
    case 11:
      return 30;
      break;

      //for february
    case 2:
      if (isThisLeapYear(year)) {
        return 29
      } else {
        return 28;
      }

    default:
      return 99;
      break;

  }

}

function convertMonth_ddToDDD(thisMonth) {
  var month = thisMonth;

  switch (month) {
    case 1:
      return "January";
      break;
    case 2:
      return "February";
      break;
    case 3:
      return "March";
      break;
    case 4:
      return "April";
      break;
    case 5:
      return "May";
      break;
    case 6:
      return "June";
      break;
    case 7:
      return "July";
      break;
    case 8:
      return "August";
      break;
    case 9:
      return "September";
      break;
    case 10:
      return "October";
      break;
    case 11:
      return "November";
      break;
    case 12:
      return "December";
      break;

    default:
      return "Unknown";
      break;
  }
}

function convertDayNumber_to_dayName(dayNo) {

  switch (dayNo) {
    case 0:
      return "Sunday";
      break;
    case 1:
      return "Monday";
      break;
    case 2:
      return "Tuesday";
      break;
    case 3:
      return "Wednesday";
      break;
    case 4:
      return "Thursday";
      break;
    case 5:
      return "Friday";
      break;
    case 6:
      return "Saturday";
      break;
    default:
      return "UnknownDay";
      break;
  }
}

function setThisSelectedDateToTextBox(selectedDate) {

  var curMonth = document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMonth").innerText;
  var curYear = document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_lblYear").innerText;
  document.getElementById("txtDate").value = selectedDate + "/" + curMonth + "/" + curYear;
  //alert(selectedDate + "/" + curMonth + "/" + curYear);
}
```

Comment: You should explain what the code is doing by adding comments or information not inside the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string dateStart = txtStartDate.Text;
            string dateEnd = txtEndDate.Text;
            DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateStart, "MM/dd/yyyy",null);
            DateTime endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateEnd, "MM/dd/yyyy",null);

            ArrayList dayResult = new ArrayList();
            if (rbtType1.Checked)
            {
                int selectedDayOpt = Convert.ToInt32(ddlEvery.SelectedValue);
                int selectedCalOpt = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCalDates.SelectedValue);

                while(endDate > startDate)
                {
                    dayResult.Add(startDate);
                    switch(selectedCalOpt)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            startDate = startDate.AddDays(1 * selectedDayOpt);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            startDate = startDate.AddDays(7 * selectedDayOpt);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            startDate = startDate.AddMonths(1 * selectedDayOpt);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            startDate = startDate.AddYears(1 * selectedDayOpt);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                string selectedDayName = Convert.ToString(ddDay.SelectedItem);
                int selectedWeek = Convert.ToInt32(ddNthWeek.SelectedValue);
                int selectedMonthDiff = Convert.ToInt32(ddMonthDifference.SelectedValue);

                while(endDate > startDate)
                {
                    string dayName = startDate.ToString("dddd");
                    if(dayName.ToUpper()== selectedDayName.ToUpper())
                    {
                        int weekNo = Convert.ToInt32(startDate.Day) % 7 == 0 ? Convert.ToInt32(startDate.Day) / 7  : (Convert.ToInt32(startDate.Day) / 7) + 1;
                        if (weekNo == selectedWeek)
                        {
                            dayResult.Add(startDate);
                            startDate = startDate.AddDays((selectedMonthDiff * 28) - weekNo);
                        }
                    }
                    startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
                }
               
            }
            gvDates.DataSource = dayResult;
            gvDates.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```